# Casting inherited class on base class reference

Tags: c#, oop

How can I access the fields of object of inherited class through base class reference using casting?

For example, how can I access the grade field in SpecificStudent class?

The casting that I try here does not work.

Thanks!

```
namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student[] students = new Student[2];

            students[0].name = "somename";

            students[1].name = "anothersomename";
            
            students[1] = (SpecificStudent)students[1];
            // students[1].grade         //This is what I want to be able to do

        }
        class Student
        {
            public string name;
        }
        class SpecificStudent:Student
        {
            public string grade;
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `students` is still an array of `Student[]` so you won't be able to access the property directly from the array. You will need to cast it from `Student` to `SpecificStudent` before you can access the property. You would need to do `((SpecificStudent)students[1]).grade`.

Comment: You should `Student[] students = new SpecificStudent[2];`. You've derived a new class and encapsulated new members, then use it directly to access the new members directly. The exposed members of the base class are accessible in a derived class. Right? Also, use public properties instead of public fields.

Comment: @dr.null `Student[] students = new SpecificStudent[2]` would still not let you access a member as a `SpecificStudent` - it would just make the cast safer.

Comment: @DStanley I'm sorry that was a mistake. I meant `SpecificStudent[] students = new SpecificStudent[2];`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use casting directly

```
((SpecificStudent)students[1]).grade
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student[] students = new Student[2];

            students[0].name = "somename";

            students[1].name = "anothersomename";

            Console.WriteLine(((SpecificStudent)students[1]).grade);

        }
        class Student
        {
            public string name;
        }
        class SpecificStudent : Student
        {
            public string grade;

        }
```

If you equal `student[1]` to `(SpecificStudent)student[1]` you are recasting the specific into `Student` again since your array is of type `Student`. If you want you can use it directly or create another array

Answer (score -1):

Here's how you *should* do it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Student[] students = new Student[2];

    Student student = new Student();
    student.name = "somename"
    students[0] = student;
    
    SpecificStudent specificStudent = new SpecificStudent();
    specificStudent.name = "anothersomename";
    specificStudent.grade = "B";
    students[1] = specificStudent;
}
```

or

```
SpecificStudent specificStudent = students[1] as SpecificStudent;
if (specificStudent != null)  // the cast succeeded
{
    specificStudent.grade = "B";
}
```

There's no way to *safely* downcast to a subtype. You can check to see if an instance *is* that type (which the `as` operator does), but a blind cast can fail at runtime.